# AP Calculus Extrema Help

Tags: calculus, derivatives

A particle moves along the t-axis with displacement $s(t) = t^4-8t^3+18t^2+60t-8$. Find the largest and smallest values of its velocity for $1<=t<=5$.

So is this correct:

- $v(t) = s'(t) = 4t^3-24t^2+36t+60$

Now do I solve for $v(t) = 0$, so $4t^3-24t^2+36t+60 = 0$, so $t=-.958$

So, $s(1) = 63, s(5) = 367, s(-.958) = -41.084$

Would the maximum be s(5) and the minimum be s(-.958)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You found the velocity correctly, but to find its extrema you need to equate acceleration to zero, and to find acceleration you need find derivative of the velocity. It factors nicely as $v^\prime(t) = 12 (t-1)(t-3)$ so you would have no problem with locating the extrema.

Comment: Oh, wow that's what I was missing. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** To find the largest and smallest values of its velocity, you have to find $v'(t)=0$

Comment: He equated $s'(t)$ with zero.

Comment: You're right! I didn't notice the "prime" in $v'(t)$. +1